# Using Google Open ID Connect to Access User's Gmail Account

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid, google-openid

How can I run a google apps script API on multiple gmail accounts? I currently have a script that accesses a user's gmail when it is authorized by the two files shown below. I store the refresh token for the client once the code asks for authorization. However, how can I use Open ID to get authorization for various users' accounts? Do I need to store a client id in addition to a refresh token to gain authorization for a user's gmail account? Thanks for taking the time to help in advance!

**read_email.php**

```
<?php
    require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    function getEmails (){
        session_start();

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
        $client->setScopes(array(
        'https://mail.google.com/'
        ));

        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){
                header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/email_database/php/oauth2callback.php');
            }

            // Get the API client and construct the service object.
            $service = new Google_Service_Script($client);
            $scriptId = '**********************';

            // Create an execution request object.
            $request = new Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
            set_time_limit(0);
            $request->setFunction('test');
            $response = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request);
            $response = $response->getResponse();
            $response = $response['result'];
            return ($response);


        } else {
            $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/email_database/php/oauth2callback.php';
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }

    }

    ?>
```

**oauth2callback.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
include 'functions.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/email_database/dashboard/php/oauth2callback.php');
$client->setScopes(array(
'https://mail.google.com/'
));
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/email_database/dashboard/php/read_email.php';
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$user = getUser($username);
if($user['refresh_token'] == null){
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
        //echo $_GET['code'];
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $google_token = json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);
        print_r($google_token);
        $refresh_token = $google_token->refresh_token;
        addRefreshToken($username,$refresh_token);
        //header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

}
else {
    $refresh_token = $user['refresh_token'];
    $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken();
   // header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```